# Call plugs from within a plug

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a few plugs that I call every time. I would like to create a single plug that calls all of them for me. How would I go about doing that?

This is what I've currently tried to do:

```
defmodule MyApp.SpecialPlug do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(default), do: default

  def call(conn, default) do
    plug SimplePlug1
    plug SimplePlug2, args: :something
  end
end
```

but it throws a `CompileError`, saying: `undefined function plug`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply use [`Plug.Builder`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Builder.html) for this:

```
defmodule MyApp.SpecialPlug do
  use Plug.Builder

  plug SimplePlug1
  plug SimplePlug2, args: :something
end
```

This will define `init` and `call` automatically which will sequentially pass `conn` to `SimplePlug1` and then `SimplePlug2`.

---

If you really want to call a plug manually, you can do something like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.SpecialPlug do
  def init({opts1, opts2}) do
    {SimplePlug1.init(opts1), SimplePlug2.init(opts2)}
  end

  def call(conn, {opts1, opts2}) do
    case SimplePlug1.call(conn, opts1) do
      %Plug.Conn{halted: true} = conn -> conn
      conn -> SimplePlug2.call(conn, opts2)
    end
  end
end
```

<sub>Note that you will have to add the check for `halted: true` yourself as above (unless you want to ignore halts for some reason). `Plug.Builder` does the same for you automatically</sub>

To get the equivalent of:

```
plug SimplePlug1
plug SimplePlug2, args: :something
```

you can now do:

```
plug MyApp.SpecialPlug, {[], [args: :something]}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. This solves my problem, but another question: How can I use Plug.Builder to compose other plugs with my (non-plug) code? i.e. can I use the `plug/1` method within the `call/2` method of a plug?

Comment: You can plug your own implementation between `SimplePlug1` and `SimplePlug2` via `plug :hello` and then define `hello/2`. Or do you want to add plugs based on your code inside the `call/2` function?

Comment: Your `hello` example seems like a great way of doing this, but still curious how would I call a plug inside `call/2`, do something with it, and call another plug on the new `conn`.